# Check if numeric and compare value in conditional with &&?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, numeric

In PHP, if there is a conditional like this:

```
if ( is_numeric($my_var) && $my_var == 1 ) {

}
```

If the first part of the if is false, does the second part (`$my_var == 1`) get ever executed?

Thanks!

Comment: No it doesn't, that's "lazy evaluation" for you - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the `$my_var == 1` will not be executed (if it's not numeric). PHP will determinate that the first part evaluated to `false` and so there is no benefit in executing the second part because you are using the `&&` AND operator.

An example:

```
if(isset($_GET['something']) && $_GET['something'] == '1')
{

}
```

If the querystring variable `something` is missing then it doesn't check if it equals `1`. If it did then it could produce an `Undefined index` notice.

You can also verify this behavior with something like:

```
$test = '2';
if($test == '1' && die('dead'))
{

}

echo 'execution continues....';
```

Set `$test = '2'` and the `die()` will not stop execution. Set it to `1` and the die will execute and stop, thus you won't see `Execution continues...`

Edit: there is some general [information here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) (not PHP specific).

Comment: Can you point to documentation to back this up (answers supported by evidence at better answers)? I've had a look at the operators section of the PHP manual but I can't find any reference to this behaviour.

Comment: @Quentin I also can't find a reference, if anyone has one then feel free to throw it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the first condition is `false` second one will not be executed if you use `&&`. You can try it yourself:

```
function a(){
echo 'a';
return true;
}

function b(){
echo 'b';
return true;
}

if (a() && b())
{
    //do something
}
```

This will output: `ab`.

```
function a(){
echo 'a';
return false;
}

function b(){
echo 'b';
return true;
}

if (a() && b())
{
    //do something
}
```

Outputs `a`.

I gave you this example because I couldn't find anything in docs but the first comment in [this section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

This is called a *call-by-need* or *lazy evaluation*.

**Note:** In some cases it's useful or necessary that the second function is executed despite of the state of first condition. In that cases you can use [`&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). With bitwise operators you  work with numbers, not with booleans. Because php interpretator should know both value before and after `&` operator it will execute both functions (`a() & b()`) and `true`, `false` are evaluated as `1` and `0`, respectively, `1 & 0 => 0` that will be evaluated as `false` in `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
if ( is_numeric($my_var)) {

    if($my_var == 1)
        {
            // your code
        }
}
```

Comment: I know I can do this. I am wondering if I do it the other way what PHP does.